# How to delete file of source after copying in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I am developing function that copy file from Temp Folder to Drive C.
After copying, I would like to delete file in Temp Folder.
I tried following codes but can't delete file.Please explain it to me.

sample codes:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
File = file of Temp Folder
objFSO.CopyFile File, "C:\"
objFSO.DeleteFile(File)

OR

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
File = file of Temp Folder
objFSO.CopyFile File, "C:\"
Set delFileName = objFSO.GetFile(File)
delFileName.Delete delFileName
```

Comment: The 1st example should work, assuming the file is not read-only/locked; what error do you see?

Comment: Error [Cannot Write] happens at line [objFSO.DeleteFile(File)]

Comment: The file may be locked/insufficient permissions

Comment: Did you try `objFSO.DeleteFile(File, True)`?

Comment: or `objFSO.MoveFile source, destination`

Answer (score 0):

Copying a file from one location to C:\ and then deleting the version in the original location is the same as moving the file, so do that instead:

```
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.MoveFile File, "C:\"
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

If you really really want to do it in the way you've described then:

```
Dim objFSO : Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
On Error Resume Next
objFSO.CopyFile File, "C:\"
If Err.Number = 0 Then objFSO.DeleteFile File
On Error Goto 0
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

will do the trick.